# if statement checking class of a div

Tags: jquery

I want to check the class of a div and change it to the other one when clicked.

Something must be wrong with my if statement.

I will appreciate a lot.

```
$("#mapresize").click(function() {
    if (this.className == "mapexpand width100") {
        $("div", this).attr('class', 'mapcollapse width100');
        $("#checkin-gmap").animate({
            height: '500px'
        }, 500, function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        });
        // $(".checkinmap-control").show("500");
    } else {
        $(this).attr('class', 'mapexpand width100');
        $("#checkin-gmap").animate({
            height: '250px'
        }, 500, function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        });
        // $(".checkinmap-control").hide("500");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Do you know toggle http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is you use the word `class` which is a reserved word in JavaScript.

```
if ($("div", this).attr(class) == "mapexpand")
```

You should use the string "class" like that:

```
if ($("div", this).attr('class') == "mapexpand")
```

Actually you could get rid of the `if` statement completely.
You can use the [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function for toggling the class.

Also there is no need to use `hide()` and `show()` when you can use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) (in the commented line).

You can use `toggle` with two functions so there is no need to check for the class to decide which animation to perform.

Like that:

```
$(".mapexpand").click(function() {
    $("div", this).toggleClass('mapexpand mapcollapse');

    $("#checkin-gmap").toggle(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '500px'
        }, 500, function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '250px'
        }, 500, function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        });
    });
    // $(".checkinmap-control").toggle("500");
    return false;
});
```

P.S. You should never check for existence of a class like that with `attr`. Imagine there are several classes in the `class` attribute. You would have to separate them and check each one if it matches yours. See [all class-related jQuery methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) and use them instead.

Comment: but problem with this one, I need to change my the class to `mapcollapse`.

Comment: @Efe this was not in your original question.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I didnt realize if statement was messing that up

Comment: @Efe I have updated my answer to toggle the `mapcollapse` class as well.

Comment: @Efe If you need to make different changes to the elements in the different cases you could use the two functions in the `toggle` function.

Comment: Wow this makes a different effect now. The map is initially open on the website with `height: 250px`. With what you have above, when clicked on the expand button, it disppears

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26578/discussion-between-efe-and-haralan-dobrev)

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) in jQuery

```
if($('#mydiv').hasClass('mapexpand')){

  $("#checkin-gmap").animate({
        height: '500px'
    }, 500, function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
 }else
{ .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `hasClass`, `removeClass` and `addClass` ... try this:

```
$(".mapexpand").click(function() {
    var j = $("div", this);
    var cls = 'mapexpand';
    if (!j.hasClass(cls)) {
        j.addClass(cls);
        $("#checkin-gmap").animate({
            height: '500px'
        }, 500, function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        });
        // $(".checkinmap-control").show("500");
    } else {
        j.removeClass(cls);
        $("#checkin-gmap").animate({
            height: '250px'
        }, 500, function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        });
        // $(".checkinmap-control").hide("500");
    }
```

Comment: silly, this works with expanding but it does not work with changing the div class to mapcollapse

Answer (score 0):

Try `hasClass` instead:

```
if ($("div", this).hasClass("mapexpand")) {
     ............
```